# Twitter Bootstrap navbar-collapse overlapping navbar-header

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am having an issue with the twitter Bootstrap navbar-collapse overlapping the navbar-header logo 'the alpha' and preventing the link to be clickable.

see picture below: alpha has an href link but is not clickable due `div.navbar-collapse` overlapping.
Here's the link to the live website: http://alchuang.com/indexnav.html

[image: Note alpha is not clickable]

```
<div class="navbar navbar-default nav-show" role="navigation">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <i class="fa fa-bars fa-lg"></i>
        <i class="fa fa-times fa-lg" style="display:none;"></i>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#viewer"><span class="logo">α</span></a>
    </div>
    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#works">Works</a></li>
        <li><a href="#manifesto">Manifesto</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
  </div>
</div>
```

What seems to be the issue here?

Comment: Your problem is not clear and you should include the relevant code in your question.

Comment: @Dan I've clarified my question. thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears that two elements on your `.navbar` are causing the issue:

`-webkit-perspective:1000` and `-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden`

These are elements that relate to 3D transformation of objects on the page - and somehow they are distorting the clickable area on your logo.

These styling don't appear to be in use on the navbar, and removing them from your `.navbar` class will fix the issue.

Comment: hey, i was also going to say that to remove `.navbar * {
-webkit-perspective: 1000;
-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
}` this. at that time, i saw a new answer.

Comment: @Ravimallya Yeah - weird issue.  Those must be inherited from whatever template OP is using.

Comment: Thanks! I recalled that I used those styles because i was experiencing glitches on the navbar when testing on my iPhone. However, they have since been resolved and I forgot to remove those styles. Great catch guys!